# Settings 20.04 will not open

Tags: gnome

Running Ubuntu 20.04 installed on an internal HD with Windows 10 on another HD. Using GrubtoWin to select initial operating system. When left click "Settings" icon a " appears in the top left corner, and "settings" text is show at the top but nothing else seems to change so i believe there are perhaps two "desktops" operating, but I do not know how to alter this? When icon is "right" clicked the small window shows a down arrow (sorry about the error above) which (when clicked) opens a small "preview" of the settings window. But that is as far as I can get. Many thanks for your help, I wish to use this as my main operating system, but am getting very frustrated.

Comment: Why not use the default Grub that Ubuntu installs ?

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't aware that Ubuntu had a system that allowed choices of operating options. years ago I used to use one, but it seemed to have been removed.

However this still doesn't answer my problem as described above. I am desperate for help